# How to I achieve this?

Tags: cv

How do I achieve this:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Personal Details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \large
 XXX \\
 ssn, \hfill \phone 123456 \\
 yyy (North Extn.),\\
 zzz,\\                                          
 aaa.\\
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

And what are the standard margins for a resume??

Comment: Standard margins for a resume might vary from country to country.

Comment: Looks like a letter? `\documentclass{letter}`??? Or should it be something like a business card?

Comment: The question, as it stands, is unclear. Please specify what you mean by "this".

Comment: The distance between the minipages has to increased and margins are to be modified @Jubobs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set each of the sides in a `[b]`-ottom aligned `tabular` (margins have been added in the image below with the aid of [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}% Times Roman-like font
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l}
  \textbf{JOHN DOE} \\
  No.\ 8, I - Floor, I - Cross \\
  ssn, \\
  XXX, \\
  Yyy
\end{tabular} \hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{l@{}}
  Ph: 123456 \\
  abcd@gmail.com
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```